# How is thermal energy and dipole related?

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

My textbook states :

> The extent of polarization of dielectrics depends on the relative strength of two mutually opposite factors - the dipole potential energy tending to align the dipole with the external field and thermal energy tending to disrupt the alignment.

I know that thermal energy arises due to random motion of particles in a substances. It's high for gases and low for solids as the molecules only have vibrational motion in the latter.

I am confused as to how they'll affect dipole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thermal energy CAUSES the random motion of particles. The more thermal energy there is, the more the dipoles will jiggle around randomly. This makes their orientation more random, so less line up with the external electric field. This effectively lowers the polarization.

Comment: Does that mean as the dielectric comes in contact with external field the thermal energy will increase.? I assume the dielectric to be a solid so it's thermal energy must be relatively less.

Comment: Bringin it into contact with the external field will cause the jiggling dipoles to, on average, rotate into the direction of the field. This causes extra motion of the dipoles, and as thermal energy is jsut molecular mnotion, it should increase the thermal energy by a small amount. An interesting application is dielectric heating https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating where the electric field is repeatedly reversed to multiply the small effect into a big one.